# Fit/Scale image that has graphics/text on it to 100% width/height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[I have an image](http://az860851.vo.msecnd.net/release/site/3DScantoPrint_landing_hero.jpg) that is 1920x1080 in resolution. The image was created by a graphics team, and has a lot of text/graphics on it. I'm not sure if there is a way with CSS and/or JavaScript/jQuery that when the page loads, this image is taking up 100% of the screen at load. The user can then scroll down past it and view the rest of the page's content.

Right now I am trying something like this (using Bootstrap):

```
<header>
    <img src="http://az860851.vo.msecnd.net/release/site/3DScantoPrint_landing_hero.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    <div id="event-callout">
        Ciudad de México Marzo 7th o Marzo 8th 2016
    </div>
</header>
```

It's not working out too well, because as the viewport size starts to approach 1770px, the image starts being vertically taller than the height of the window, therefore causing some of the text within the image to scroll off the page.

I'd like to just have the image fit to the screen size on load (at 100% of the page's height on load). I've tried multiple solutions involving jQuery, and CSS, but none seem to fit these basic requirements. Is it even possible?

Edit: Another attempt here

```
#hero {
    background-image: url(http://az860851.vo.msecnd.net/release/site/3DScantoPrint_landing_hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}


<wrapper id="wrapper">
    <div id="hero"></div>
</wrapper>
```

This solution doesn't fit the image to the screen as it scales down.

Edit 2: jQuery attempt here

```
#hero{
  background-image:url(http://az860851.vo.msecnd.net/release/site/3DScantoPrint_landing_hero.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
}

<wrapper id="wrapper">
    <div id="hero"></div>
</wrapper>

$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    handleScroll();
});

function fullscreen() {
    $('#hero').css({
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()
    });
}

fullscreen();

// Run the function in case of window resize
$(window).resize(function () {
    fullscreen();
});
```

Yields the same results as the CSS version it seems.

Comment: Can you post your attempts, especially your CSS attempts?

Comment: @Mikey Added CSS and jQuery attempts. Both following [this guide](http://www.web2feel.com/creating-a-fullscreen-hero-div-for-your-site-header/)

Comment: I think you are missing some css rules for the background-image: did you try this: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: @Mikey that is full-page background images. I'm looking for full-screen image... like a hero image that takes up 100% width/height upon load, but doesn't fill the entire page's background. https://www.google.com/drive/ has an example of what I'm looking for kind of, but note their image doesn't have any text on it... and as it gets smaller some of the content of the image goes away... so I guess that's not what I'm looking for and may not be possible.

Comment: _“The image was created by a graphics team”_ … and that seems to be a large part of the problem here. Most of the text in that image should not _be_ part of an image, but set as actual text content in HTML.

Comment: @mariocatch Oh sorry, didn't see that.

Comment: How do you expect this to work?  You can't make it fill the screen without stretching or clipping it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? ... and by adding a bottom padding it keeps its aspect ratio.

```css
html, body { margin: 0; }

#hero {
    background-image: url(http://az860851.vo.msecnd.net/release/site/3DScantoPrint_landing_hero.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;    /* 1080 / 1920 = 0.5625 */
}
```

```html
<div id="hero"></div>
<div class="content">
 Bla bla<br>
 Bla bla<br>
 Bla bla<br>
 Bla bla<br>
 Bla bla<br>
 Bla bla<br>
 Bla bla<br>
</div>
```

---

Sample 2

```css
html, body { margin: 0; }

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
}

.hero img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height:100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <img src="http://az860851.vo.msecnd.net/release/site/3DScantoPrint_landing_hero.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is close, but the bottom part of the image is not shown on-screen (the blue bar with text on it).

Comment: @mariocatch I can read "ESCANEO 3D ..." and the rest. Do you mean one need to scroll to see it?

Comment: I cannot see it on 1920 x 1080 resolution. I have to scroll to see it. I'm trying to figure out how to keep it on the screen on page load.

Comment: @mariocatch Added a 2:nd sample ... will that help you?

Comment: @mariocatch Did my answer help you or do you need more assist?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
       html,body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
       }
    img{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://az860851.vo.msecnd.net/release/site/3DScantoPrint_landing_hero.jpg" alt="Hero">
<div>Other</div>
<div>Other</div>
<div>Other</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, this causes the image to stretch further than the width of the screen, and cuts off the bottom part of the image.

Comment: which resolution are you testing it on

Comment: 1920 x 1080 resolution

Comment: This seems to work fine on my 1920 x 1080 and also 1366 x 768 display... I will investigate further

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved you the problem ?
https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/yuf56uv0/

```css
img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real answer to this, as the comments have indicated, is that there is no way to do this while maintaining the aspect ratio and readability of the image as the screen size changes.

The solution is to not take a huge image with all of the text/graphics on it and try to use it, and instead to break it up into components, and piece them together on the page using html/css accordingly. That way they can move/shift around as the screen size changes, while still keeping the message clear.